# How to make horizontal dropdown menu like this in WP

Tags: windows-phone-8

[image]

I need to show items in dropdown menu in line. How can i make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to build the Control yourself.  You can make a Composite Control consisting of a `<Button>` and a `<ListBox>` to emulate what you're trying to do.   It is actually pretty easy.

For example:

```XAML
<Button Content="{Binding SelectedItem.Song, FallbackValue=Show List, ElementName=myListBox}" Height="100" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
<ListBox x:Name="myListBox" Height="60" Visibility="Collapsed">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Height="50" Padding="15,0">
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Run Text="{Binding Song}"></Run>
                </TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>                
</ListBox>
```

---

What I did here is programmed a Button with its `Content` Binded to the ListBox's SelectedItem  which has .Song Property, if none is selected it falls back to "Show List"

When the user clicks on the button it should hide/show the list box depending on its current Visibility.

```C#
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.myListBox.Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed)
    {
        this.myListBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else
        this.myListBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

---

Your job is to wrap all this up inside a nice UserControl or you can just use it as is.

Here are some screenshots of it in action:

[image]